# Suppress build errors for ASPX files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

How can I turn off errors during project build for `.aspx` files? If there are any open files, the compiler show all errors, while I want only to see C# code errors.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply close the file in Visual Studio. This will prevent IntelliSense to precompile it. That's the only way to do this. It's called a feature ;)

Comment: This doesn't help. If i try to click on .aspx file  in errors list I receive "Visual studio encounters error" message, even if i close it explicitly , i still get this file in error list.

Comment: @alekoo73: I don't get that here. If I close the ASPX file, all errors on that page disappear from the dialog.

Comment: This receipt is very simple,but it doesn't work, the only way is to restart visual studio, closing all open files beforehand.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code in the page? It doesn't give the described behavior here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload complete solution here,I have VS 2013 Update 4 ,just MVC project with old fashion .aspx files.The question is much broader ,how to suppress errors list for .aspx files, not the errors in my code

Comment: @alekoo73: I know, but I can't reproduce it here. Closing solves the issue here, so it would be nice to have an example.